# Replace a part of a Python list element

Tags: python, string, list, csv, replace

I have a csv file like below:

CSV:

```
H1,H2,H3
A_B,C1,D
F_2j,G,p5
```

I'm trying to remove '_' and numbers from the first column. Here's what I've tried

```
for i in range(len(max(cols, key=len))):
        transposed = ([(c[i] if i<len(c) else '') for c in cols])
        str(transposed[0]).replace("_",";").split()
```

It did replace '_', but the original transposed still prints the same csv file. How can I replace this new column with the old? Also, how can I remove digits just from column1 to give the following output?

Desired output:

```
H1,H2,H3
A;B,C1,D
F;j,G,p5
```

Comment: you just want output or write to another file???

Comment: @Hackaholic I just want output because there's more processing that I'd be doing after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import re

with open("in.csv") as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    out.write(next(f))
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in r:
        out.write("{},{}\n".format(re.sub("_\d+|[_\d+]", ";",row[0]), ",".join(row[1:])))
```

Comment: bro why not to use _\d*

Comment: okie you have taken other possibilities too but it was not in input , but its nice :)

Comment: @Hackaholic, I presumed there was the possibility of any combination. That was the bit that was unclear until now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be a basic misunderstanding of the behavior of `replace` - it returns a copy of the modified string, but does not modify the string in-place.  To have the replacement "take", you'd have to assign it back to the original string.  Consider the following:

```
>>> text = 'blah_blah_blah'
>>> print(text.replace('_', ';'))
blah;blah;blah
>>> print(text)
blah_blah_blah
```

As you can see, the original `text` string is untouched by the `replace` call.  To actually modify it:

```
>>> text = text.replace('_', ';')
>>> print(text)
blah;blah;blah
```

As for eliminating numbers, you can go with the regular expression-based approach in the answer from @Hackaholic (which will nicely handle the '_' to ';' conversion as well) - I just thought there would be benefit in shedding light on the behavior the `replace` method for strings.

Comment: @Thank you. But will it work when I have multiple columns and I want to edit only column1 because this way it replaces all the _'s in 'text' and assigns it to 'text' again.

Comment: @dan, you cannot use normal str.replace to do what you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Your deleted answer worked for me. Thank you. I might not have phrased my question properly but that was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
import re
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for x in f:
        print re.sub("_\d*",';',x)   # here you can store it in variable and do procession on it
```

output:

```
H1,H2,H3
A;B,C1,D
F;j,G,p5
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i checked it, its working fine, it dosent effect header

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Python's CSV Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to both read and write. This may end up simplifying a lot of the logic you already have. Make sure you are actually writing the rows to a file (I don't see that in your example code). I also suggest using regular expressions for the substitution and deletion:

```
sub = re.sub("_\d*", ";", my_column)
# use sub as your new column
```

*Edit*: I misread what OP wanted regarding digit removal. It's ambiguous about the rules of when to wipe the digits (only after a _ character? All digits IF there is a _?). Used OP's example output as the rule ("all digits after an _")

Comment: If there was only a digit, it would effectively blank out the cell in the CSV file. So, if my row was "1,two,three", I would get ",two,three". This is valid and just means the first cell is empty

Comment: That's true, I didn't see that the digit removal is dependent on the "_". It's ambiguous about the rules regarding when to remove numbers, but if we assume digits directly after the "_", then this should be done in a single `sub` call like what others suggest: "_\d*"